# foreach loop and get different query and result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

```
$day1=date('d');
$add2 = strtotime("+ 1 day");
$day2=date('d', $add2);
$add3 = strtotime("+ 2 day");
$day3=date('d', $add3);
$add4 = strtotime("+ 3 day");
$day4=date('d', $add4);
$add5 = strtotime("+ 4 day");
$day5=date('d', $add5);
$add6 = strtotime("+ 5 day");
$day6=date('d', $add6);
$add7 = strtotime("+ 6 day");
$day7=date('d', $add7);

$month=date('m');
$year=date('Y');

$alltime=array("12:00PM", "12:30PM", "1:00PM","1:00PM","1:30PM","2:00PM","2:30PM","3:00PM","3:30PM","4:00PM","4:30PM","5:00PM","5:30PM","6:00PM","6:15PM","6:30PM","6:45PM","7:00PM","7:15PM","7:30PM","7:45PM","8:00PM","8:15PM","8:30PM","8:45PM","9:00PM","9:15PM","9:30PM","9:45PM");

$allday=array($day1,$day2,$day3,$day4,$day5,$day6,$day7);

foreach($alltime as $time)
{
    foreach($allday as $day)
    {
        $check="Select * From restaurant,reservation where restaurant.resid=reservation.resid and time='$time' and date='$year-$month-$day' and username='$username' and status='active'";
        $result=mysql_query($check);            
    }
}
```

I am trying to create basic weekly calendar with specific times in array. That code below is working no problem. Only problem is $check and $result stay the same name.

after that I am checking with mysql_num_row($result) code and execute it. But no luck... Because $result and $check should be different

I want to get them:

```
$check1=sql

$result1=$check1

$check2=sql

$result2=$check2

...

$check203=sql

$result=$check203
```

format inside foreach so I can take it and do whatever I wanted to with it.

I used

```
for($i; $i<=203; $i++)
```

foreach result was crazy long and it didn't work.

So How can I do $check and $result with unique number or anything that I can separate from each other?

Answer (score 2):

This way is terribly slow and will do a lot of queries with no results. A better way to it would be to query for all reservations and then in PHP fill in the gaps where there are no reservations found.

```
SELECT
    time, date, id, name, etc
FROM
    restaurant
    INNER
     JOIN reservation
       ON restaurant.resid=reservation.resid
WHERE
    date BETWEEN $start AND $end and username='$username' and status='active'
```

Where `$start = date('d-m-Y', strotime('midnight'))` and `$end = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+7 day, midnight'))`